# Recursion producing extra empty lists in Clojure

Tags: recursion, clojure

This question is about an exercise for this course: http://iloveponies.github.io/120-hour-epic-sax-marathon/sudoku.html

My implementation to function `solve` returns the solved sudoku board but in addition surrounding it are a lot of empty lists. All of my other functions work properly and don't return any empty lists. I can't figure out why this happens.

Here's the relevant code:

```
(defn solve [board]
  (if-let [point (find-empty-point board)]
    (let [valid-values (valid-values-for board point)]
      (for [value valid-values]
        (solve (set-value-at board point value))))
    (if (valid-solution? board)
      board)))

(def sudoku-board
  (board [[5 3 0 0 7 0 0 0 0]
          [6 0 0 1 9 5 0 0 0]
          [0 9 8 0 0 0 0 6 0]
          [8 0 0 0 6 0 0 0 3]
          [4 0 0 8 0 3 0 0 1]
          [7 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 6]
          [0 6 0 0 0 0 2 8 0]
          [0 0 0 4 1 9 0 0 5]
          [0 0 0 0 8 0 0 7 9]]))
```

Output:

```
(solve sudoku-board)
(((((()) ())
((((((() (())) (())) ((() (())) ((()))) ((()) ((()))))))
(() ((((() (())) (())) ((() (())) ((()))) ((()) ((()))))))
(((((() (())) (())) ((() (())) ((()))) ((()) ((())))))))
((()) (())))
(((((((() (())) (())) ((() (())) ((()))) ((()) ((()))))))
(() ((((() (())) (())) ((() (())) ((()))) ((()) ((()))))))
(((((() (())) (())) ((() (())) ((()))) ((()) ((())))))))
```

...

```
(((((((((((((((([[5 3 4 6 7 8 9 1 2]
                                                    [6 7 2 1 9 5 3 4 8]
                                                    [1 9 8 3 4 2 5 6 7]
                                                    [8 5 9 7 6 1 4 2 3]
                                                    [4 2 6 8 5 3 7 9 1]
                                                    [7 1 3 9 2 4 8 5 6]
                                                    [9 6 1 5 3 7 2 8 4]
                                                    [2 8 7 4 1 9 6 3 5]
                                                    [3 4 5 2 8 6 1 7 9]]))))))))))
```

...

```
((((((((()) ((((((()) (()))))) (((((((()))) ((())))))))) ((((((() ()) (())))) ((((() ()) (()))))) (())))
                  (((((((() ())))) ((((() ()))))) (()) (((((() ())))) ((((() ()))))))
                   ((((())) ()) ((() (())) (()) (())))
                   (((() (((())))) (()) (())) (((((())))) ())))
                  (((()) ((((((()) (()))))) (((((((()))) ((())))))))) (((((((((((((()))))))))))) ())))))
                ()))))))
          ())))))
     ())))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As coredump says, you need to be more careful combining the results of your recursive calls. In particular, notice that your "return type" is not consistent: in the `else` branch of your `if-let`, you return a single solution, but in the `then` branch you return a list of solutions as produced by `for`.

In order to make it possible to call your function meaningfully, it should return a consistent type: a list of solutions. Here's a simple change that changes the return value to always be a list, and makes sure to concat all the sublists to avoid introducing extra levels of nesting:

```
(defn solve [board]
  (if-let [point (find-empty-point board)]
    (let [valid-values (valid-values-for board point)]
      (for [value valid-values
            solution (solve (set-value-at board point value))]
        solution))
    (if (valid-solution? board)
      [board])))
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`for`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for) construct accumulates each value computed in the body of the list comprehension as a lazy sequence. When you call solve recursively, you are computing such sequences inside nested sequences, etc.

You should probably append those lists so that the result is flattened.

Personally, but I am not sure how idiomatic Clojure it is, I would just accept a callback function `fn` and perform a `doseq` instead of `for`, so that for each solution board, you only need to call `fn` on that board (you implement a generator). Up to the caller to do whatever it wants with solutions.

Comment: `for` is already a generator. Using `doseq` and a callback instead would be very poor style when a simple solution exists using lazy sequences.

Comment: @amalloy That's why I suspected. Thanks

Comment: @tuulik You probably should accept the other answer